# Proper Application Isolation in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Realizing that AppDomains no longer exist in .net core, what is the appropriate way to create app isolation within a .net core webapi?  Will this be taken care of by the ASP.NET MVC framework?  I plan on having the code run in a Linux environment.

Comment: From [Porting to .NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/): "For code isolation, we recommend processes and/or containers. For dynamic loading of assemblies, we recommend the new AssemblyLoadContext class."

Answer (score 1):

No this won't be addressed by the framework. Isolation is generally an OS concern. By the time .NET takes hold it's too late, it can't be done in a secure way.

Basically run your apps in different processes, app pools, or whatever your OS provides.